# Firebase hosting a React Native - how to setup so part of my project is on main domain and part on subdomain?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm using Firebase hosting to host a react native app (deploying the build, so in firebase.json my public path is "build"). I want to have a subdomain (app.example.com) to host some pages.

I don't understand how to set up and deploy a project so some of my pages are on the main domain and other pages are on the subdomain. Is this even possible or do I have to have two different react projects and two different firebase projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a youtube video that helped me figure out the structure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ayNDsqtjHs

Essentially you have two react projects and one firebase project. In the firebase.json config you add both react projects to the hosting object pointing the public object to each build. So, something like this.

```
{
"hosting": [{
  "target": "app",
  "public": "my-project-app/build",     
}, {
  "target": "public",    
  "public": "my-project-public/build",      
}]
```

}

And then in the Firebase hosting webpage you "Add another site". Follow the instructions. And then you link your two projects to an alias in a terminal by running

```
firebase target:apply hosting app my-project-app;
firebase target:apply hosting public my-project-public;
```

And then to deploy you build each react app and deploy individually:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:app;
firebase deploy --only hosting:public;
```

Lastly, back on the firebase hosting page you can go into your new subdomain site that you just created and find the button for "Add custom domain" so you can point use your custom subdomain (app.example.com) with the new site.